# Load Application on to external HDMI/VGA display

Tags: display, external-display, ubuntu-16.04

I have connected one external Display to my laptop( means connected one HDMI display) which contains Ubuntu 16.04 as the OS. I would like to display content like VLC player, Firefox etc only on this external display using command line interface. Tried with DISPLAY command but didn't succeeded.

Could someone help me on this.